# how to merge array in single class object array in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i had total 6 arrays in ionic 2 ts file.I want to display all array in table.
So i want to merge this arrays in one array.Kindly give me any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array spread operator (...)`;

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [7, 8, 9];
const arr2 = [5, 5, 5];

const resultArr = [...arr1, ...arr2];
// resultArr is [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9];
```

Or you can spread and push an array:

```
resultArr.push(...arr3);
// resultArr is [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array `concat` method

```
var a = [1, 2], b = [3, 4], c = [5, 6];
var d = a.concat(b, c);
console.log(d);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
// [1, 2,3,4,5,6];
```

Comment: i had all array in different datatypes.Thanks for the suggestions